# Change the min scale without changing the max on a chart

Tags: c#, devexpress

I have a chart that should allow the end user to assign a min and max to it at runtime. The parameter is defaulted to 0, so if a value is chosen the statement will execute. The problem I am having is that I need only the minimum to change and for the maximum to stay the same as it was. I cannot figure out what should go in the max value. Any suggestions?

```
    int thirteen = Convert.ToInt32(this.Parameters[13].Value);
    if (thirteen > 0)
    {
        ((SplineSeriesView)xrChart1.Series[0].View).AxisX.Range.MinValue = this.Parameters[13].Value;
        ((SplineSeriesView)xrChart1.Series[0].View).AxisX.Range.MaxValue = // insert something here!
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply take the statement out completely. It is not needed if the value is to "stay the same as it was."

Comment: If I do that, the chart does not show correctly. It is expecting a max.

Comment: Then this is a question about DevExpress, or the application in which you are using it, not C# at all. Have you tried setting a breakpoint on the .MaxValue line and seeing what the value is?

Comment: When I put an integer in the MaxValue it works. So I know that it is expecting a value.

Comment: All right, then what exactly is the problem you are trying to solve? If you put an integer into MaxValue it works. Surely you've put a *specific* integer in there. What is the problem with that as a solution?

Comment: Sorry if I tagged my question incorrectly but I assumed this was c# code.

Comment: Each graph has a specific max. One might be 2015, and another might be 2050. The only solution I have came up with is to read the value of a calculated field that has the max value in it and use that. However, I was wondering if there was an easier way to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: Again, this question has everything to do with how your application is designed, and very little to do with C# or even DevXpress. If your research indicates that the calculated field gives the correct result, then that is the right answer. Without going through your application we really can't do better than that.